# Excel formula to get highest and lowest value and seperate it by -

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a way to get from this:
130 | 140 | 150 (that's one cell in excel)

these are all the heights suited for a product and i want to get one field showing the range

to this:
130 - 150

So it should basically separate the values with the "|" and then only take the highest and the lowest value and separating it with a "-"

Is there an easy way to get this done? It wouldn't be a problem if it takes a few steps

Answer (score 5):

I could imagine your input is not sorted? Try:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" - ",,CHOOSEROWS(SORT(--TEXTSPLIT(A1,,"|")),1,-1))
```

[image]

Comment: I was going to answer `=LET(r,--TEXTSPLIT(A1,,"|"),CONCAT(MIN(r)," - ",MAX(r)))` but I like your answer better so I don't want to compete.

Comment: can't get it working for some reason. I'm guessing it's partly because i'm using excel in german and it doesn't take english forms, I'm using the form translator from excel tho and I still get the same error. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You could ***try***:

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

---

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
=TEXTJOIN(" - ",,TAKE(SORT(TEXTSPLIT(A1,,"|")*1),{1,-1}))
```

---

**Note:** The `1` & `-1` within curly braces of the `TAKE()` function.

• A **positive** value : Takes the number of row(s) from the start of the array;

• A **negative** value : Takes the number of row(s) from the end of the array.

---

Data used same as **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir's. Answer posted as an **alternative**, inspired by **JvdV Sir's answer**.